# How to deal with returning many different types from Azure DocumentDb/CosmoDB?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Azure DocumentDb/CosmoDB and i've got a really kludgy pattern i need to get out of.

I have a WebAPI controller that I return my objects from based on an ID. I also have a repository that will query the DocumentDB depending on .  The problem is, I've got about 30 different types (and growing) and i have to do something like this:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetWidget(String id, String widgetType)
        {
            if (widgetType.Equals("WidgetA"))
            {
                DocumentDbRepository<WidgetA> repo = new DocumentDbRepository<WidgetA>();
                var widget = await repo.GetItemAsync(id);
                return (ControllerContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, widget));
            }
            else if (resourceBase.SystemType.Equals("WidgetB"))
            {
                DocumentDbRepository<WidgetB> repo = new DocumentDbRepository<WidgetB>();
                var widget = await repo.GetItemAsync(id);
                return (ControllerContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, widget));
            }

        ...
     }
```

I know, this is terrible.  I'm thinking of using reflection or maybe even some T4 templates to generate all this but I'm thinking there must be a cleaner way?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are all widget types in the same collection?

Comment: @BrendanGreen yes they are